# Windows shortcut to COMPLETELY maximize a window

Tags: windows, keyboard, shortcuts

So in the past I had found a keyboard shorcut that once pressed it maximized the window and with the top bar hidden. So it was completely maximized and I had to press it again to exit that mode. When the window was maximized, the top bar with the three buttons on the top right to minimize, maximize and exit was hidden so the window was fully maximized. I believe it was something like Ctrl ~ but it doesn't work, I cannot remember that shorcut and I really want to use it again. Also I do not remember setting something up in Autohotkey or something, so that shorcut should have been native to Windows 10.

Comment: Do you accept autohotkey scripts to configure it?

Comment: @Biswapriyo If it is possible why not! However I do not understand how it worked without using Autohotkey. I am not sure what happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remembered the shortcut I was talking about. This shortcut does not work on most apps, and I am not sure if it is a shortcut by Windows.
I am using this shortcut to fully maximize Adobe apps like Premiere, After Effects, Photoshop etc. The shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl \</kbd> but it doesn't work on most other apps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following key combos:

- <kbd>F11</kbd> - Kiosk Mode / Fullscreen
- <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> - Maximize

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am aware of F11 however I am talking about another shortcut. Yes it is a similar - almost the same effect but it does not work in everything. So if I press F11 when I am in Chrome it works but when I am in Adobe After Effects it doesn't work. That shortcut I used in the past worked in other apps as well. @Moab

Comment: Then why did you not say that in your question...F11 does exactly what you explained above. "So it was completely maximized and I had to press it again to exit that mode. When the window was maximized, the top bar with the three buttons on the top right to minimize, maximize and exit was hidden so the window was fully maximized." Some apps have their own special shortcuts, you would have to google those.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>win</kbd> + <kbd>up arrow</kbd> to maximise